# Winsock: Echo server replying twice, when I just programmed it to do one send() call

Tags: c++, windows, winsock2

I am doing a simple TCP server in C++ for Windows to echo incoming data. I have a problem with it. Before I explain my problem, I have to say that Winsock is properly set up and this problem happens with any IP address as the source.

The general behaviour when a connection is established is this:

> In the loop that runs while connection still alive, it must echo data, and precede it with REPLY word.

To do that, I'm currently using two send() calls:

- One call sending "REPLY " alone.
- Another call just sending back received data.

But using Putty Client, I'm getting this:
    REPLY data_echoed REPLY.

Why REPLY is sent after the last send call if it was the first??? I'll post a little code where the problem happens:

```
//Reply to client
message = "HELLO CLIENT!! READY TO ECHO.\n";
send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);

///Enter into a loop until connection is finished.
printf("%s \n\n", "Incoming data goes here: ");
do{

    ///Clear buffer and receive data.
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    ret = recv(new_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);


    printf("%s", buffer);

    ///Send a REPLY WORD and the data echoed.
    send(new_socket, "REPLY\r\n", 7, 0);
    send(new_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

}while(ret != SOCKET_ERROR);
```

What is wrong with that? I'll remove the first call, and the double effect disappears. Why I can't do two send calls one after other?

Comment: I'm not implying this is the root cause for your issue, but pls note you're sending back to the client the _entire buffer_ , sizeof(buffer), even though you might received less bytes than sizeof(buffer)

Comment: @ShmilTheCat I have tried with Putty, and it seems to send back properly the data, but just with an added "REPLY" word. I have tested it writting my own client, and it sends me 1000 bytes, the amount expected. But it continues doing a double send() when I just use one

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to `ret`? Also, try null terminating the buffer received and/or sending `strlen(buffer)`.

Comment: @Brandon I done that. I think that ret not needs to be initialized, but I initialized it and nothing changes. Also, I have null-terminated the string, but the problem persists. I am doing this first using strings as a test case, and later I'll be switch to binary data if the problem is fixed.

Comment: You don't need the `memset()`, and you  need to exit this loop if `ret == 0`. And what's a 'bucle'?

Comment: @EJP I use it to be sure that the data is overwritting the previous data. About ret == 0, I did know that, but that it's not causing errors, at least I think that. Sorry for 'bucle' word, it's a mistake because I am spanish-speaker. I am looking for on internet, but i can't found a solution.

Comment: @DeanWinchester It *is* causing errors. It is one way to cause *this* error. It will cause you to print and echo data that you haven't received, which is exactly the problem you described. Add `if (ret == 0) break` immediately after the `recv()` call. Similarly you should test for -1 immediately after the `recv()` call, instead of doing all those sends and then checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ignore the return value of `recv` until after you send `REPLY`, so no matter what happens, you send `REPLY` followed by the contents of the buffer. After you echo the first time, something happens, and no matter what it is, you send `REPLY`.

Bluntly, it doesn't look like you understand the very basics of TCP. We used to have a rule that before anyone can do anything with TCP, they must memorize and completely understand the following statement: "*TCP is a byte-stream protocol that does not preserve application message boundaries.*"

Your code pretends that it is receiving and echoing application-level messages. But there is no code to actually *implement* application-level messages. TCP has no support for application-level messages, so if you want them, you have to implement them. You clearly want them. You also have not implemented them.

Do newline characters delimit messages? If so, where's the code to find them in the data stream? If not, what does?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that means that packages are arriving in random order??? I thought that if I send A, B, C, I must get A, B, C. Sorry if I do beginner mistakes, I have no many time programming.

Comment: You're writing code at application level. There are no "packages" at application level. What happens on the network is TCP's business. The application sends *bytes* and receives *bytes* because TCP is a *byte-stream* protocol that provides a stream of bytes. If you send "HELLO" and then "GOODBYE", you might receive "HELLOGOODBYE" or you might receive "H" and then "ELLOGOODBYE". TCP does not preserve application message boundaries. TCP has no support for application-level messages. If you want messages (and it's clear you do) you have to code them (and it's clear you didn't).